# numbering a funk-olicious list with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

I am using `.scrollable` to scroll a bunch of scientific papers for my client (beside the point) and I need a jquery argument to number the individual div entries like so

first entry in the html

```
36.
37.
38
39.
40
31
32
33
34
35
28
29
30
31
32
etc.
```

im currently using

```
$(window).load(function(){  
        $(".scrollable").scrollable({ vertical: true, mousewheel: true});               

    var increment=-1;
   var start=40; // THIS CONTROLS THE NUMBERING OF THE INDIVIDUAL PAPERS OR IP ENTRIES, CHANGE start=# TO THE NUMBEER THAT YOU WANT THE FIRST ENTRY TO HAVE
    $("div.item-number-ip").each(function(i) {
       $(this).prepend('<span>'+(start+i*increment).toString()+'.</span>');
       });  
});
```

but obviously that just number them from 40 down to 1....the client wants people to scroll his articles starting with the most recent 40 - 35 BUT he wants 40 listed on the bottom of the first page and not the top.

Comment: I don't understand the jumps in the numbers in the example. Could you clarify?

Comment: Also, you can simplify the code to `$(this).prepend('<span>'+(start-i)+'.</span>');`. No multiplication or explicit `.toString()` needed.

Comment: You should provide more details about Scrollable.  Only people familiar with [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/scrollable/) might know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want, but it's slightly unclear:

http://jsfiddle.net/6e6md/

I think your last 5 numbers in your example list of numbers is wrong.  If not then I'm not sure what you're looking for.

This would need to be adjusted to your exact code, but I think this gives the number ordering you're looking for.